# How to extract a folder name from a path stored in a variable with CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

In a CMD batch file, it's easy to extract the path/folder name for an argument:

```
set folder=%~f0
set dirname=%~p0
```

It's described in `help call` and `help for`.
Now how do I do the same with a path stored in a variable?
The following doesn't work:

```
set VAR="c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin\java.exe"
echo %~pVAR%
```

The alternative I found is to use either FOR or CALL:

```
for %%A in (%VAR%) do set P=%%~pA
for %%A in (%VAR%) do set N=%%~nA
for %%A in (%VAR%) do set E=%%~xA
```

and then use %P% (c:\path), %N% (appname), %E% (.exe) as I need.

For example, I recently needed to convert a java.exe variable to map to javaw.exe instead, so I end up writing this:

```
if %java_exe%=java (
    set javaw_exe=javaw
) else (
    for %%a in (%java_exe%) do set p=%%~pa
    for %%a in (%java_exe%) do set n=%%~na
    for %%a in (%java_exe%) do set x=%%~xa
    set n=%n:java=javaw%
    set javaw_exe=%p%%n%%x%
)
if not exist %javaw_exe% set javaw_exe=%java_exe%
```

Can someone shine in with a better solution that doesn't look totally hackish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no other way to do what you need. The only improvement in your code is that several values may be taken in the same `for`, and the elimination of one line:

```
if %java_exe%=java (
    set javaw_exe=javaw
) else (
    for %%a in (%java_exe%) do set p=%%~pa& set n=%%~na& set x=%%~xa
    set javaw_exe=%p%%n:java=javaw%%x%
)
if not exist %javaw_exe% set javaw_exe=%java_exe%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

:: go the run dir
cd %~dp0
:: this is the dir containing the batch file
set MyDir=%CD%

for %%A in (%0) do set MyDriveLetter=%%~dA
for %%A in (%0) do set MyPath=%%~pA
for %%A in (%0) do set MyName=%%~nA
for %%A in (%0) do set MyExtension=%%~xA

ECHO MYNAME IS %0
echo MyDriveLetter is %MyDriveLetter%
echo MyPath is %MyPath%
echo MyName is %MyName%
echo MyExtension is %MyExtension%

PAUSE
```